# Send Mail from ccnet

Tags: email, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

On ccnet service has about 3 project.
Every time build fail, i want send mail to me. I can know and fix at time.
Please help me, how does set up mail server and config file ccet.config.
Thanks everyone...

Comment: You need to give your CC.NET version.  It changed over time, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

The [CruiseControl.net website](http://cruisecontrolnet.org) has quite a detailed example of how to use the `EmailPublisher` which is what you will want to use.

See: http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Email_Publisher